# MVC Required TagHelper working with FluentValidation ASPNET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to have a little red asterisk rendered automatically on form fields that require validation and have the validation metadata provided by FluentValidation.

I'm 50% of the way there however the using the `When(....` clause is causing some problems.

A simplified example is:
A tag helper

```
public class NjordInputTagHelper : TagHelper
{
public override void Process(
            TagHelperContext context,
            TagHelperOutput output)
        {

            IValidator validator = _factory.GetValidator(For.Metadata.ContainerType);
            if (validator == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            IValidatorDescriptor description = validator.CreateDescriptor();

            IEnumerable<IPropertyValidator> propertyValidators = description.GetValidatorsForMember(For.Metadata.PropertyName);


            if ((For.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(bool) && For.Metadata.IsRequired ) 
                //|| propertyValidators.Any(p=> p is NotNullValidator || p is NotEmptyValidator )
                )
            {
             //insert asterisk
            }
        }
}
```

My validator

```
public class MyValidator: AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
         When(x=>x.MyPropertyA != null, () => 
         {
            RuleFor(x=> x.MyPropertyB).NotEmpty();
         })
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to only enable some validation if a condition is true. So when `MyPropertyA != null` I want to ensure `MyPropertyB` is `NotEmpty()`

All works fine, except when in my tag helper, as you can see I am checking for either `NotNullValidator` or `NotEmptyValidator` and the `NotEmptyValidator` is always present, in this context, it doesn't run the `When(...` condition because when the page is being rendered I know for sure that `MyPropertyA` is null

Maybe I am missing something?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public MyValidator()
{

  RuleFor(x=> x.MyPropertyB).NotEmpty().When(x=>x.MyPropertyA != null);

}
```

Comment: I believe you've slightly misunderstood the issue but thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Mr_M is right `When` should work. But it seemed to me, you want to apply the method to several fields, judging by your validator code. So you can do this:

```
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelValidator()
    {
        When(x => x.MyPropertyA != null, rules: new[]
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.MyPropertyB).NotEmpty(),
            RuleFor(x => x.MyPropertyC).NotEmpty()
        });
    }

    private void When<T>(Func<MyModel, bool> predicate, IEnumerable<IRuleBuilderOptions<MyModel, T>> rules)
    {
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            rule.When(predicate);
        }
    }
}
```